# Delegate in C# attribute

Tags: c#, mono, activator

I am looking to put a static delegate inside of a custom attribute. What I am running into is Activator.CreateInstance is a major bottle neck and I'd like to avoid it. I am using Mono and running on iOS so compiled lambda and any JIT'd method is out of question. What I was hoping to do is put a static factory constructor on each class that has the attribute. So it would be something like:

```
[CustomAtt("cool",FactoryMethod)]
public class SomeClass{
    public static SomeClass FactoryMethod(){
        return new SomeClass()
    }
}
```

This gives me a compile error `An Attribute must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression`

The reason I was going to stick it in the attribute is all of the objects I will be creating already have the attribute and I have the attribute when I need to create the object.

Is there another way to accomplish this, or another faster way of creating objects.

Comment: The error message seems pretty straightforward.  The expression that you're using is not a constant, `typeof`, or an array creation expression.  A delegate creation is none of those things.

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/7XxIg7, you can get some notion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(v=vs.110).aspx). Specify the method name and the type, find the method with reflection (once) and then create a delegate from it. You could potentially do that within the attribute constructor, although I typically do very little in attribute types themselves. Another alternative would be to make whatever's *consuming* the attribute do the work and cache the delegate.

Although this requires reflection and the ability to create a delegate on the fly, I would expect both of those to be supported within Mono on iOS (by which I assume you mean Xamarin.iOS, unless you're rolling your own solution).

Comment: This worked great and led to ~20x speed up for our use case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will end up having `String` in your attribute, as Jon suggested in his answer (so if you are going with that route, credit goes to him).

However, if you are able to invoke a method by its name using reflection, you can as well invoke a constructor (as [`ConstructorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), without using `Activator.CreateInstance`) for the given type. Then you won't need to have any custom attribute pointing to the factory method; constructor *is* a factory method. I would suggest considering this alternative then.